# How do I write a program which checks whether the numbers or letters in the string follow the given pattern?

Tags: java, regex, algorithm

I'm trying to write a program which accepts any two numbers and checks if they are in the given pattern:

abb abbb abb abbb abbb abb abbb abbb abbb abb abbb abbb abbb abbb abb

I have put spaces for making it clearer. As you can see it follows a pattern in which everytime there is 'abb' followed by 'abbb', the number of times 'abbb' occurs in every iteration increases by 1. So it is something like this:

In every iteration:
abb(abbb++)

I'm trying to figure out how to do this using pattern library in Java but haven't got any solution yet.

Comment: What's the input and expected output?

Comment: Input is any string which is to be checked whether it follows the given pattern or not. The output is a Boolean which tells whether it follows the given pattern or not. I was given this in a aptitude test, tried solving myself but wasn't able to do it using pattern class in Java. I'm still looking how it could be done.

Comment: @user47 if I am not wrong your pattern is abb(abbb)+

Comment: You can use regex for matching do add the tag regex in your question

Comment: Regex alone can’t do it. You would have to also write code to check the matched terms grow correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand the amount of `abbb` is incremented each time `abb` is met.

Then, validate with

```java
^((abb|\1)abbb)+$
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/X2VeqD/1).

**Java code**:

```java
yourString.matches("((abb|\\1)abbb)+")
```

**EXPLANATION**

```java
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1 (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      abb                      'abb'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \1                       what was matched by capture \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    abbb                     'abbb'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )+                       end of \1 (NOTE: because you are using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \1)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

If you meant to extract, use

```
abb(?:abbb)+
```

See [this regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/X2VeqD/2).

**EXPLANATION**

```java
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  abb                      'abb'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    abbb                     'abbb'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )+                       end of grouping
```

**Java code**:

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String regex = "abb(?:abbb)+";
        final String string = "abbabbb\nabbabbbabbabbbabbb\nabbabbbabbabbbabbbabbabbbabbbabbbabb\nabbabbbabbabbbabbb\n";
        
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Regular expressions in java, read more on [Regular expression API in java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

```
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    System.out.println (Pattern.matches("abb(abbb)+","abbabbb"));
```